# Problems converting C++ code to C - pointing to beginning of array

Tags: c, type-conversion

I need to compile some code originally written in C++ in C for a specific platform.  I am having problem with the line below which is attempting to set p to the start of outputdata as below.

I am getting a compiler error error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before 'type'

How do I need to change this to compile in C?

```
size_t example_function(unsigned char** outputdata, size_t *output_length)
{
   *outputdata = (unsigned char*)malloc(20);

   unsigned char* p = *outputdata;

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which line are you getting the error on? I'm having a hard time seeing anything wrong with this.

Comment: The code is compiling just right: no errors or even warnings. Could you provide a little bit more code (before and after your function) and specially the compiler and options you're using?

Comment: Missing `size_t` maybe? Try `#include <stddef.h>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm guessing that you are using the Visual C++ compiler to compile this. This compiler only supports C90 (aka C89), so you will need to put declarations before any other statements in any block.

```
size_t example_function(unsigned char** outputdata, size_t *output_length)
{
    unsigned char* p;

    *outputdata = malloc(20);

    p = *outputdata;

    return 0;
}
```

I am assuming that you have (directly or indirectly) included `<stdlib.h>` for definitions of `size_t` and `malloc` otherwise you would probably have a different error.

Comment: C99 would allow the declarations as they are in the original code.  Your answer is probably still right, though.  Since `p` is never used, why bother having it there anyway?

Comment: @CarlNorum: I assumed that C2143 was a Microsoft compiler error. If that assumption is correct then the rest of the answer should be correct. re: `p` being unused, I don't know; I was just fixing the code as written.

Comment: There aren't any MS compilers that speak C99 are there?  Regardless, C99 explicitly supports declarations like those in the original poster's example.  I agree that your answer is probably correct - it's just that C99/C90 aren't as you describe them.

Comment: @CarlNorum: I have fixed the typo that you pointed out, thanks.

Comment: Yes that was problem.  Don't do much C work - so forgot about the C declarations having to go before anything else.  thanks.  Also just to add - it is a really old MS compiler - v6.0 vstudio.

Comment: @user619818 And this is why you should clearly indicate *which line of your posted code* is the line on which the compiler is indicating an error. We don't like having to guess.

Comment: Hi Greg, if you read the question again you might notice it does in fact state the line with the error.